# Scope is not filling when I try to set it after a ajax request

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get data from an API and using this data to make up Google Maps.
But unfortunately it's not working when I set data in side of .then().

This is my controller

```
var alertController = function alertController($scope, alertData) {

// Local variable private variable
var _data;

// Retrieving data from API
alertData.getData()
    .then(function(data){
      _data = data;
      // Setting scope variables
      $scope.options = {
        scrollwheel: false
      };
      $scope.markers = alertData.locations;
      $scope.map = { center: { latitude: _data.latitude, longitude: _data.longitude }, zoom: 16 };
    })
    .catch(function(data, status, headers, config){
      $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
    });

// _data is undefined here, how can i make it "defined"
}

alertApp.controller('alertController', alertController);
```

My service

```
function alertData($http){
  var alertData = {};

  alertData.getData = function() {
    var settings = {
      "url": "url",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
      "Auth-Token": "token",
      "Content-type": "application/vnd.api+json",
      },
      "data": "{ data }"
    }
    return $http(settings);
  };

  alertData.locations =  [
        {id: 1, latitude: 52.012812, longitude: 4.365468, title: "1"},
        {id: 2, latitude: 52.012832, longitude: 4.365475, title: "2"},
        {id: 3, latitude: 52.012843, longitude: 4.365448, title: "3"},
        {id: 4, latitude: 52.012843, longitude: 4.365238, title: "4"},
        {id: 5, latitude: 52.012812, longitude: 4.361748, title: "5"},
        {id: 6, latitude: 52.012865, longitude: 4.3653458, title: "6"},
        {id: 7, latitude: 52.012876, longitude: 4.365768, title: "7"},
        {id: 8, latitude: 52.012865, longitude: 4.365348, title: "8"},
        {id: 9, latitude: 52.012845, longitude: 4.365758, title: "9"},
        {id: 10, latitude: 52.012834, longitude: 4.3654475, title: "10"},
        {id: 11, latitude: 52.012816, longitude: 4.3654345, title: "11"},
        {id: 12, latitude: 52.012826, longitude: 4.365472, title: "12"},
        {id: 13, latitude: 52.012815, longitude: 4.365457, title: "13"},
        {id: 14, latitude: 52.012838, longitude: 4.365427, title: "14"},
      ];

  return alertData;
}

alertApp.factory('alertData', alertData);
```

The HTML

```
<div id="container" class="container" ng-controller="alertController">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' options="options" zoom='map.zoom'>
          <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
          </ui-gmap-markers>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
      </div>
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve waiting till I get data and than fill the scope and let Google Maps init?

**UPDATE**

When I `console.log(_data)` after `getData()`, it says undefined and come before the console.log(_data) inside of the .then() which gives the right json

Comment: What's the value of `data` inside `.then(function(data){...` ? Any errors on _console_? What is showing the _network tab_ on your _devtools_?

Comment: are you really making any call?

your url is ```"url": "url",```
is it dummy code you pasted here or the acutal one?

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro no errors because it is getting data normaly, but I think the problem is that it initializes maps before any data is received.

Comment: @PranavJindal Thats dummy code, because the real url I may not publish

Comment: So, I assume `data` is populated OK. Is that right?

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro Yes thats right. it's just that _data is undefined when i log it after the .then(). but when i log it inside the .then() its good

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro please see update

Comment: Well, by seeing your code again which says `// _data is undefined here, how can i make it "defined"`. The short answer is:: you can't. You have to wait until the async call is resolved (inside the `then`)

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro so how can I know if the async call is resolved and than fill my scope?

Comment: You're actually doing it so, when you say `$scope.data = _data;` The key point here is: when are you initializing your map or whatever object which needs `$scope.data = _data;`? You should do it when the async is resolved

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro you right that's exactly the problem, but I don't know when maps is initialized. I'm using angular-google-maps.js and I don''t know when it does it

Comment: I have not worked with `ui-gmap-google-map` before.... but when you say `ui-gmap-google-map options="options"` and so on, `options`,  shouldn't be initialized? What is that variable? What's the role of `$scope.data`? I don't see any data in your controller related to your google map component. Please, correct me if I missed something here

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro you are deffenitly right, see my updated controller, i'm not $scope.data was just for test. And no options does not need to be initialized, but thats a good one, maybe i can make it wait via the options

Comment: @apero, please the answer I posted. The explanation was to large to be posted as a comment. That might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I suggest you to put a condition for showing your google map only when all required data is ready, so this way you can wait until all data is ready for "building" the component. Something like this:

```
<div id="container" class="container" ng-controller="alertController" data-ng-if="dataReady">
        <!-- google maps component here-->
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
// Retrieving data from API
  alertData.getData()
    .then(function(data){
      //...
       $scope.dataReady = true;
    })
    .catch(function(data, status, headers, config){
      //...
    });
```

**Important:** Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show/ng-hide` since the first one creates/removes elements from the DOM and the second one just applies css classes for displaying or not the component. With the `ng-if` the google maps component is created when all required data is ready.